# How does windows handle unregistered windows?

Tags: windows

Usually when you're making a windows application, you begin by registering a window class. Something like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc; 

    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; 
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, "favicon.ico"); 
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, "favicon.ico"); 

    /******important bit******/
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
```

But what happens you don't do this? Would the program still show up in the Task Manager? How does windows handle unregistered programs differently to registered programs?

Comment: Wrong mental image, creating a window requires a window class.  If you don't create a window then you still see the process back in the Processes list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegisterClassEx` doesn't register your application, it registers a window class, i.e. a template to create windows of that kind (most importantly including the window procedure, plus various extra base attributes). If you don't create any windows, there's no need to call `RegisterClass` (for example, console applications or services typically don't do any `RegisterClass`).

On the other hand, if you don't register a window class but then try to call `CreateWindow`/`CreateWindowEx` referring to its name, then such calls will fail, and the respective windows won't be created/shown.

As for the task manager, window class registration is irrelevant; what matters is whether you create any window (which you may not be able to, if all your `CreateWindow` calls fail because you didn't register the corresponding window class). If an application doesn't show any window, it won't be shown in the running applications tab, but of course the process will still be visible in the processes list tab.